# New Basement Bathroom Drain Issue

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement, drain, venting

First off, I live in Virginia, I know plumbing code varies state by state. I am roughing in a bathroom in my basement. I was planning to use a shower drain as my sink drain that is already in my concrete slab. I went to remove the P-trap that is subgrade and found out it is 24" below grade!!!! Why, I have no idea...... I am wondering if I am able to drain bathroom sink directly into my main for the house (3" going into slab). This all has to pass inspection, any advise would be greatly appreciated. (The venting will be provided by a studor vent)

Comment: Its a bit unclear, a photo or a diagram might help

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt go to your local building department and ask the inspector about it. If he tells you it has to be purple make it purple and he will pass it. He is the guy that has the final say.